# Parse external webpage and extract all URLs and link text from the content

Tags: php, string

I want to parse external webpages and extract all URLs and link text from the content using PHP.

For example,

```
$content="<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> google</a> is very good search engine <a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail </a> is provided by google.
```

Output:

```
http//google.com      google 
http//gmail.com     Gmail
```

Suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the url and text using regular expressions then the following should work:

```
<\s*a\s*href\s*=\"(?<url>.*)\">(?<text>.*)</a>
```

However parsing `HTML` with `RegEx` is not a good idea, you can use [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class instead.

**Edit**

```
$content = "< a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> google</a> is very good search engine < a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">Gmail </a> is provided by google .";

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($content);

$anchors = $html->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
       echo $anchor->getAttribute('href') . "\t" . $anchor->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: DOM How can write the program using php.I don't have any idea with DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can use this REGEX pattern `href="([a-zA-Z0-9://. ]+)"`

Example usage

```
$pattern = 'href="([a-zA-Z0-9://. ]+)"';
$content = file_get_contents(FILE NAME HERE);
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

This will list all links . ANd then you can parse them.